# Advantage of a "step by step" sign up form

Tags: user-behavior

I have noticed that big companies such as Facebook and Twitter use a "step by step" sign up process for their mobile apps instead of a single form. Is there an advantage for that?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is an advantage for that.

If they would ask for every information at once, most of the people would aboard the ship and don't continue with the registration.

Showing the users only chunks of informations at once elevates the chances of registration.

Also its more easy to focus on smaller chunks of input instead of looking at a big fat wall of many different fields.

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely true - Chunking does reduce the amount of information the brain needs to process at any given time but, If I see a sign up process is 5 or 6 steps long then I won't sign up - or worse, if I get more than 3 steps in and there's no sign that I'm almost done, I'll abandon it there. I think this is more to do with technical constraints around security but I don't know enough about the technicalities to give an answer there

Comment: I agree with what you say, but if you get a registration form that is 6 steps long then something might be wrong with the registration process itself, there would be no difference if you would just put all necessary information on one page, users still wont like to finish the registration and im 100% sure people would rather finish a long step by step form then a long wall of text registration any day. Also the psychological side of "i already entered data so lets just get this over with" is a fact that is helping the step approach.